# Why was my helpful comment deleted?

Tags: discussion

My first comment to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25058134/javascript-split-a-string-by-comma-except-inside-parentheses) was deleted by moderator George Stocker. The reasoning was that the comment is

> a philosophical argument about what a newbie should or should not know.

**It was not** -- my comment merely made the observation that regular expressions or a naive `split()` would not do the job and OP should try writing a recursive descent parser instead. When I asked why my comment was - unjustly - deleted, he answered:

> Be truly helpful, not "well I pointed him in the general direction." Helpful.

Which is rude and is not an explanation, nor is it warranted. I want my comment back -- it did no harm and added value.

Comment: Moderators are human too and, in my opinion, *often* make choices that the rest of us would consider a mistake.

Comment: @Ben But this is **unjust!** And he does not even admit he made a mistake. Now he tries to convince me (see the follow-up comments) that I should avoid answering the question in the comments -- it isn't even remotely close to what I was doing! I left a comment that helped OP start looking for a solution at the right place. I was *not* trying to answer the question in a comment.

Comment: I think this already came across in your post.  There is not much I can do to help except agree with you and to express some frustration that this is not an isolated case.

Comment: @Ben Yeah, I know you can't do anything about it... it's just... it's just way too unfair and not professional at all.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant while I agree that your comment _was_ helpful (and a way better response to OP than simply writing him a parser, or even as George suggests explaining how to write such a parser in an answer), **unjust** is a pretty big word for the deletion of a simple comment. The first comment from George seems to imply that he deleted way more than just a small comment saying "use a parser", seems like there was an off-topic discussion going on. If so, I'd say your comment was simply collateral damage - I doubt it would have been deleted on its own.

Comment: @l4mpi yes, there was a discussion, **which my comment was not part of.** That's why I consider this unjust - this is like sending someone to jail for being the *neighbor* of a burglar. (especially that the mistaken deletion could be trivially undone -- it seems to me that it's really just due to that moderator's haughtiness that he does not want to undelete it. Admitting he made a mistake would apparently hurt his feelings.)

Comment: Thankfully two other users focussed at the question and provided a working solution...

Comment: @rene yeah, let's be thankful that another newbie got an answer he can copypaste, without investing any effort himself, and probably without learning much in the process - at least not nearly learning as much as he would have learned by writing a parser himself... OP, I understand your frustration but you'll have to understand that mods have extremely little time to spend on issues like this; often _all_ comments are just purged without checking if a few should be saved instead, as anything else would be too time-consuming. And AFAIK comments can't just be undeleted but are simply gone.

Comment: @l4mpi I believe that mods are able to undelete comments...

Comment: @l4mpi that's horrible, so basically I just have to accept any sort of unfairness happening to me and I can demand no justification because moderators are not willing to spend time on differentiating between good and bad? In this case, SO doesn't seem like a fun community to participate in.

Comment: Of course you don't have to accept "any sort of unfairness", but (1) it's just a comment - these are intentionally second-class citizens anyways, subject to somewhat arbitrary deletion (like the purging I mentioned before) and (2) even if the comment would stay around, this would not matter to anyone anymore in 30 minutes - OP has his answer, you probably don't have any interest in the question anymore, so why even care? If you choose to be outraged over something, don't choose an insignificant comment on an even more insignificant question as your reason...

Comment: Wow, it's almost like this actually mattered.

Comment: @Will believe or not, for me, it actually matters. I don't see why you absolutely had to taunt me about this.

Comment: No, I believe it does, to you.  Which is sad, because in reality it is less than trivial.   Don't spend your life fighting over trivial injustices, it makes for a miserable existence.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I got involved because one of the comments left by the person you were arguing with was flagged as 'rude or offensive'.  As it turns out, you were involved in that conversation; and your comment *started the argument*.

Your comment was deleted as part of a cleanup of the comments on that question.

Here's a screenshot of all the deleted comments, lest you think I'm making this up:

[image]

Is this your fault? No.

But, as you should know, comments are second class citizens and they have a specific purpose, as outlined in their placeholder text:

> Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid using comments to give answers

Now, was your comment either of these? *No*.

As I tried to explain to you in the comments (my mistake), if you want to give an answer (i.e., "Write a recursive descent parser") then *post that as an answer*.  If you don't want to give an answer, don't -- but don't complain because something that is purposefully ephemeral was deleted.

If you want to be helpful and give the OP useful advice, here is my suggestion:

> An answer that explains what a recursive descent parser is (Briefly), how it helps in this particular situation, and *at the very least* helpful links that show him how to implement is a helpful answer.

If your comment is *that awesome* that out of tens of thousands of comments it should be the one to stick around, *then it should be in an answer*.

Other general notes:

If someone flags a comment as 'rude or offensive', it's going to attract moderator attention to the entire comment thread, *especially* if the flagged comment is *neither* rude nor offensive.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant While I agree with your comment except for the last sentence, you should really understand that comments are just not seen as long-term posts anyways. Also, you're not censored; and your comment has in fact been undeleted. You should see this as a honest mistake caused by too little moderator time for handling comment flags and not as an oppressive action by the diabolical SO moderator force. And again, if you choose to be outraged about something, you should choose something more significant than a good comment on a bad question.

Comment: @l4mpi oh, wow, it actually was undeleted.

Comment: I figured it out because of the lack of horns and hooves. But now that I think about it, that unicorn obsession could be a bad sign...