# Ability to see own deleted comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, deleted-comments

There are numerous posts on people's confusion over deleted comments. Why can't we still see our *own* deleted comments, preferably in context, otherwise in our profiles, and the reason for deletion.

It would prevent context-less replies, and lets you self-evaluate why your comment was not worth keeping. Hopefully, this would inspire better commentary in future.

Comment: I believe that deleted comments are *wiped from disk*, unlike deleted posts which are kept, but hidden.

Comment: I doubt that comments are wiped from disk, as they could be useful in moderation actions.

Comment: Comments aren't wiped, [moderators can still see them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315725/how-can-i-deleted-comment-recovery-from-stackoverflow#comment-301713) just like deleted posts.

Answer (score 7):

Comments aren't the focus of a Q&A site, save for clarification and/or suggestive guidance.

That doesn't stop most of us from using them in other ways, but in all honesty, there's no reason to allow us to see our own deleted comments, as they'd add unnecessary noise to the overall context of a question and/or answer.

Comment: Who are you to decide what value I and others place on comments? Most answers I find have very pertinent info in the comments. Often enough a better solution than the answer, itself. So you think us plebs shouldn't be allowed to know why what we write is just gone? If noise is an issue, then don't show them in context by default, or only show them in profile. Why do you say "no reason"? I just provided *two*, and I'm sure there are more.

Comment: One of the big reasons that comments aren't valued highly is that there is no search functionality provided for them.  Further, comments that are considered too chatty or not constructive can be flagged for removal.  I'm not denying that comments have their place, but simply expressing that comments aren't the focal point of a Q&A site.

Comment: @walf if comments are being used as long term repositories of valuable knowledge then people are doing it wrong.

Comment: @Flexo There's no "if". People *are* and comments do not always contain an entire solution worthy of a separate answer. To say that "people are doing it wrong" is naive and dictatorial.

Comment: @Makoto, You're not just saying "comments aren't the focal point", though. You're saying people should not be allowed to know what content is being moderated and why.

Answer (score 2):

Comments aren't worth keeping(after a point, at least); they're designed for constructive criticism which is supposed to be listened to and incorporated in the question/answer. For example, I would comment on your question if it had something wrong(such as a java tag and ruby code, in which case I'd ask why the java tag, or whether the correct code was used).

People do use comments for conversation, but they're not intended for it, use [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) instead. Reason for this is that comments could at any time be flagged as off-topic, and if the reason for flagging is justified, removed without notice. It's like keeping cash in your child's notebook; there's no guarantee that it'll last. Use the safe instead; that's what it's there for.

About your comment of 'partial' answers in comments, if you feel that the info is valuable enough, ask the poster to write an answer and incorporate the info. I've seen it being done numerous times, and such answers even get the coveted green tickmark.

---

Here's a case for you:

The person in this question is complaining why his comment was deleted:
[Why was my helpful comment deleted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267331/why-was-my-helpful-comment-deleted)

And I must say, his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25058134/javascript-split-a-string-by-comma-except-inside-parentheses#comment38979555_25058134) on the linked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25058134/javascript-split-a-string-by-comma-except-inside-parentheses) was indeed a good example of valuable information contributed to the question asker. However, he chose to leave it at that, risking wasting that information. And that's what happened, his comment was deleted because of [it being a part of an argument, which needed to be removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267331/why-was-my-helpful-comment-deleted/267333#267333). The moderator explaining explicitly states that it should have been an answer.